# Is there a way to utilize the nullish coalescing operator (`??`) in object property destructuring?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining, nullish-coalescing

In ReactJS, I commonly use this pattern of destructurnig props (I suppose it is quite idiomatic):

```
export default function Example({ ExampleProps }) {
  const {
    content,
    title,
    date,
    featuredImage,
    author,
    tags,
  } = ExampleProps || {};
```

I can add default values while destructuring, which adds some safety:

```
export default function Example({ ExampleProps }) {
  const {
    content = "",
    title = "Missing Title",
    date = "",
    featuredImage = {},
    author = {},
    tags = [],
  } = ExampleProps || {};
```

But now I switched to TypeScript `strict` mode and I have quite a hard time. My props are typed by GraphQl codegen, and virtually all the properties are wrapped in a `Maybe<T>` type, so when unwrapped, there are like `actualValue | null | undefined`.

**The default values `({ maybeUndefined = ""} = props)` can save me in case the value is `undefined`, but the `null` values would fall through**, so the TS compiler is nagging and my code results in a lot of:

```
tags?.nodes?.length // etc…
```

which makes me a little nervous because of the [The Costs of Optional Chaining](https://betterprogramming.pub/the-costs-of-optional-chaining-eb21f357d6e2) article (although I don't know how relevat it still is in 2021). I've also heard `?.` operator overuse being referred as an example of "code smell".

**Is there a pattern, probably utilizing the `??` operator, that would make the TS compiler happy AND could weed out at least some of that `very?.long?.optional?.chains`?**

Comment: That actually looks really atypical to me. You're destructuring `ExampleProps` from the props provided in the parameter list, then destructuring it again into individual parts. Normally those individual parts would be individual props. I would expect it to be `function Example(ExampleProps)`, not `function Example({ ExampleProps })`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Yes, I was thinking that might **not** be the most idiomatic example.  These are, let's say, 'data props' (coming from NextJS `getStaticProps`). But destructuring them earlier doesn't change much, or does it?

Comment: No, not really I suppose. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible options:

1. Do the nullish coalescing property-by-property, or
2. Use a utility function

#### Property by property

Fairly plodding (I'm a plodding developer):

```typescript
// Default `ExampleProps` here −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−vvvvv
export default function Example({ ExampleProps = {} }) {
    // Then do the nullish coalescing per-item
    const content = ExampleProps.content ?? "";
    const title = ExampleProps.title ?? "Missing Title";
    const date = ExampleProps.date ?? "";
    const featuredImage = ExampleProps.featuredImage ?? {},
    const author = ExampleProps.author ?? {},
    const tags = ExampleProps.tags ?? [];
    // ...
```

#### Utility function

Alternatively, use a utility function along these lines to convert `null` values (both compile-time and runtime) to `undefined`, so you can use destructuring defaults when destructuring the result. The type part is fairly straightforward:

```typescript
type NullToUndefined<Type> = {
    [key in keyof Type]: Exclude<Type[key], null>;
}
```

Then the utility function could be something like this:

```typescript
function nullToUndefined<
    SourceType extends object,
    ResultType = NullToUndefined<SourceType>
>(object: SourceType) {
    return Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(object).map(([key, value]) => [key, value ?? undefined])
    ) as ResultType;
}
```

or like this (probably more efficient in runtime terms):

```typescript
function nullToUndefined<
    SourceType extends object,
    ResultType = NullToUndefined<SourceType>
>(object: SourceType) {
    const source = object as {[key: string]: any};
    const result: {[key: string]: any} = {};
    for (const key in object) {
        if (Object.hasOwn(object, key)) {
            result[key] = source[key] ?? undefined;
        }
    }
    return result as ResultType;
}
```

Note that `Object.hasOwn` is **very** new, but easily polyfilled. Or you could use `Object.prototype.hasOwn.call(object, key)` instead.

(In both cases *within* `nullToUndefined` I'm playing a bit fast and loose with type assertions. For a small utility function like that, I think that's a reasonable compromise provided the inputs and outputs are well-defined.)

Then:

```typescript
export default function Example({ ExampleProps }) {
    const {
        content = "",
        title = "Missing Title",
        date = "",
        featuredImage = {},
        author = {},
        tags = [],
    } = nullToUndefined(ExampleProps || {});
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
    // ...
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgUBNgGMA2BDKYOAcxwgCM8dEU464A7PAW2AGcw8siB5cgK2wwAwhAZsYUAK5YY0GvUVwAFnjY8A7gwBccABQV+uw0ICUu8hAg5geBgG5a9VKhQwAnmCIBZPO-LAADwAKp7AAHxwALxwoV5wAD6MUjjUSVIMmABmAJYMwOiObmFwAHIpOMEQAKqZwLn56CFhkTEITnQA2gDWwO5weXC97hBZsWEAuroAoiC4UpjNXj19EwA0yanhjq5ZGbI5YpuVNXUNBYEdcADKEFJQ3HFEoDDAmWxwJrJrVwBK7CkYE9omUKlVatk8hdbvdHi0UOEDAIhLoYQ9gE9TAp6FgxBI4Gw7uiQV94GpECt3LoJFA8sQpnA7O4kI5FLjxPBCGxAboEJTqZI6QymUgQchWfQsvI9Oz8cMBgxPsjZFj2kp6Dkxno+IJZAA6VTqLRI3UwDbDUyquAAemtcAAVI64AA1YBQfr5DRXdV0LmAykTEGE2HAANwAD84bgGUhjQl6tQikT9EIMHuir9ODJH3+3KzTx2aDyrygWS4RFmLDANgAClAIGA2MC1fRK8xq8A6w22LzvTixK8GDBdL5-EEaXTtn26DAcjAbCO-AFAhOGMQpz6bXa9Turi40HsGAcjm2O3oEKfa-XG0gZiAq1fu5jsXRZfAW+r2YP4DEAES-n5N1neciD-bwcjYNg6ViOcbAA6ctzgHc9T3EEGDBU5YwKPRL07a8PgSJJkFMeNELgAA9SiqOomjyMAJCIGMYpjmMY8irllaxgD1MhiBlAc3jNOBgJsEiUCQIA)

Comment: Thank you. The first option (Prop by Prop) look a little tedious (some of the properties are deeply nested) and possibly hard to maintain, but the utility function looks super cool! I was secretly thinking of converting `null`s to `undefined`s, but I wasn't sure if the idea isn't completely ridiculous. Definitely will try to implement!

Comment: @HynekS - My pleasure? Was a fun problem. I've added a playground link just FWIW.